# UIActivity Indicator Doesn't stop After called NSObject class's Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have two classes: `ClassA` and ClassB`.

- `ClassA` implements `UIViewController`.
- `ClassB` implements `NSObject`.

I have `startAnimating UIActivityIndicator` in classA's method at the same time i need to call one of the Class B's  Methods. After executing Class B's method, I'll call new classA's method and then `Stop Animating UIActivityIndicator`. Here every thing  is working fine, except `StopAnimating`. Please help me to find the solution. I don't know about threads, if I use thread, will it solve my problem?

Comment: can you post your code for both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

threading seems like a complicated way to solve this. Why not retain a the UIActivity indicator in class A, and stop animating in the method you call in class A from B.  Woo sounds complicated.

Theres not reason why you cant pass a pointer the activity indicator to any class.

If this doesn't work for you I'd look at notications rather than going down the multi-threaded route

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, use the following code

Declare the UIActivity indicator object in the .h file.

Call the following method where you want to stopAnimating.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


- (void)stopAnimation{
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: could you please clarify .h of which file ?